# What's the difference between "uintN" and "varuintN" in WebAssembly?

Tags: webassembly

What's the difference between "uintN" and "varuintN"? Why did not we directly use "varuintN" to replace "uintN" in WebAssembly?

BTW, there are only a few fields that are using "uintN" type which include "magic number" and "version".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

varuint uses [LEB128 encoding](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/LEB128), which is a variable length encoding, and therefore size efficient. I think the instances where non variable length encoding are used is places where encoding size is not a priority, e.g. storage of numeric values in linear memory